# Consume web service with JavaScript - Passing the type apachesoap:Map

Tags: javascript, web-services, apache, soap

I am attempting to consume an Axis service which was built in Java using JavaScript.

Everything is fine except for one searching operation that asks for an `apachesoap:Map` type. Here is the WSDL section for the operation:

```
<wsdl:message name="queryRequest">
   <wsdl:part name="collection" type="xsd:string"/>
   <wsdl:part name="service"type="xsd:string"/>
   <wsdl:part name="lang" type="xsd:string"/>
   <wsdl:part name="nameToValsMap" type="apachesoap:Map"/>
   ...
```

Is there any way I can pass data in such a type using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

`apachesoap:Map` is a complex type (an element) as opposed to `xsd:string` which is a value.

If I'm not mistaken `apachesoap` refers to the `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap` namespace. You are probably calling some legacy SOAP web service that exposes a `java.util.Map` directly (very bad for interoperability if I'm not mistaken).

The WSDL `<types>` should contain the definition for the complex type `apachesoap:Map` and should look something like this in the message (the WSDL should tell you the exact form):

```
<nameToValsMap>
  <item>
    <key>...</key> 
    <value>...</value> 
  </item>
  ....
  <item>
    <key>...</key> 
    <value>...</value> 
  </item>
</nameToValsMap>
```